# Source not found- YahooFinance.class

Tags: java, api, quotes, finance, yahoo

I'm trying to implement code from https://github.com/sstrickx/yahoofinance-api on Eclipse in Java. When I run the program, I'm getting a several lines of errors that are being printed on the console. When I click on the errors, it takes me to a window named "YahooFinance.class" on Eclipse that says "Source not found." It asks me to change the attached source. I have added the source to C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.11/lib/src.zip on my computer, but I'm still getting the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Screenshot of error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZuL7.png

Edit:
This is the code that I am trying to compile from source:

```
    Stock stock = YahooFinance.get("INTC");

    BigDecimal price = stock.getQuote().getPrice();
    BigDecimal change = stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent();
    BigDecimal peg = stock.getStats().getPeg();
    BigDecimal dividend = stock.getDividend().getAnnualYieldPercent();

    stock.print();
```

My project is Maven-based and I have added this dependency to the pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.yahoofinance-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>YahooFinanceAPI</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

After refreshing my project's Maven dependencies, like Kevin Hooke said to do, I am no longer getting the "Source not found" error. Thank all of you for your quick responses and help!

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- Please [edit] the poost and include the relevant (!) code.

Comment: No need to add IDE and Paths to your java or language sources.  Provide code snippets and exact dependencies you have used.

Comment: What do mean by 'implement code' - are you trying to compile this project from souce? If so have you followed that project's instructions on how to do that? Or are you trying to use this library as a dependency from your own code. Please be more explicit on what you're trying to do and what errors you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source project you're trying to use is a Maven based project and provides instructions on how to include it as a dependency.

1. Create a new Maven project in Eclipse (or update your project to be Maven based, adding a pom.xml file, standard folder structures etc)
2. Edit your pom.xml file and add a dependency to the yahoofinance-api project:

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.yahoofinance-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>YahooFinanceAPI</artifactId>
        <version>x.y.z</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
3. Replace x.y.z with the version that you need to use
4. Refresh your project's Maven dependencies: right-click project, Maven -> Update Project